# radio button selected

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

id like to alert the name of the radio button when i click each of them. but only one radio button fall in the condition. please help. im new in jquery

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container{
            width:500px;
            height:300px;
            background-color:#F9F9F9;;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">






        $(document).ready(function(){ 

            $("input[@name=testGroup]:checked").click(function(){


                if($(this).val() == "pizza"){

                    alert("pizza");

                }

                else if($(this).val()== "cake"){
                    alert("cake");
                }

            });


        });
    </script>
</head>


<body>

    <input type="radio" class="rad_but" name="food" value="pizza">Pizza</input>
    <input type="radio" class="rad_but" name="food" value="cake">Cake</input>
<input type="radio" class="rad_but" name="food" value="others">Others</input>

    <div id="container">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

every time click each of them only one radio button alerts the value. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need? [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YWHM5/)

```
   $("input[name='food']").change(function () {

        if($(this).val() == "pizza"){
         alert("pizza");
         }
         else if($(this).val()== "cake"){
         alert("cake");
         }
         else if($(this).val()== "others"){
         alert("others");
         }
   });
```

Comment: exactly.. wat does change do?

Comment: @steve-great!.That looks very much simplified.